# SAP Macro running through Excel, how to get data to populate on Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I created an SAP Macro that gets the data that I need:

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "ZPRS"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_PLANT").text = "1707"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_ARBPL-LOW").text = "BSLSR"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_ARBPL-LOW").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_ARBPL-LOW").caretPosition = 5
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
```

then What I did next was make a button with this through Excel to get the data that I need:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If Not IsObject(SAPGuiApp) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set SAPGuiApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
   Set Connection = SAPGuiApp.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject SAPGuiApp, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "ZPRS"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_PLANT").Text = "1707"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_ARBPL-LOW").Text = "BSLSR"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_ARBPL-LOW").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_ARBPL-LOW").caretPosition = 5
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press

End Sub
```

After running the script, everything works well. However, the issue that I'm having is that, the excel macro is creating a new Excel sheet every time, I want it to populate on the Excel sheet in where the button is. I don't really know how to word it and was wondering if anybody might have any insight ?

Comment: Your SAP application generates an Excel file and you want your VBA macro copy the data from this sheet, and paste it into a sheet of the Excel file containing your VBA macro. I don't think your VBA can tell the SAP application to put the data at a given place directly. Please explain how your SAP application "is creating a new Excel sheet every time" so that we can help you.

Comment: i figured it out. I ended up doing it to where it will save all exisitng workbooks desktop and reformatted the saved destination folder to where the excel file from where the macro is running to a specific folder. I then used power query editor to create the data connection.